# Servlet response.sendRedirect encoding problems

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, utf-8, character-encoding

So I'm redirecting my user using GET in a naive way:

```
response.sendRedirect("/path/index.jsp?type="+ e.getType() 
   +"&message="+ e.getMessage());
```

And this was working fine until I had to send messages, as actual text to be shown to users. The problem is if the message has non-ASCII characters in it. My .jsp files are encoded in UTF-8:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

So all non-ASCII characters in 'message' gets garbled. I don't want to set my JVM default encoding to UTF-8, so how do I solve this? I tried to use

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

on the Servlet before redirecting, but it doesn't work. when I try to execute:

```
out.print(request.getCharacterEncoding());
```

on my .jsp file it prints 'null'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `sendRedirect()` method doesn't encode the query string for you. You've to do it yourself.

```
response.sendRedirect("/path/index.jsp?type=" + URLEncoder.encode(e.getType(), "UTF-8")
    + "&message=" + URLEncoder.encode(e.getMessage(), "UTF-8"));
```

You might want to refactor the boilerplate to an utility method taking a `Map` or so.

Note that I assume that the server is configured to decode the GET request URI using UTF-8 as well. You didn't tell which one you're using, but in case of for example Tomcat it's a matter of adding `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` attribute to the `<Context>` element.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `language="java"` is the default already, just omit it. The  `contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` is also the default already when using JSP with `pageEncoding="UTF-8"`, just omit it. All you really need is `<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`. Note that this does effectively the same as `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")`, so that explains why it didn't have effect. The `request.getCharacterEncoding()` only concerns the POST request body, not the GET request URI, so it is irrelevant in case of GET requests.

Comment: I googled how to set the URI encoding on weblogic but I couldn't get it to work. By any chance you know how to set it on weblogic?

Comment: Do it in `weblogic.xml`. See also e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1039258

Comment: Ok, so using the deprecated URLEncoder.encode(String) solved my problem. I guess I could use the URLEncoder.encode(String, String) and get the charset of the JVM would solve it as well. Any problem with this approach?

Comment: You're now relying on the platform default charset which is most likely ISO-8859-1. If you're dealing exclusively with characters which are [covered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#Codepage_layout) by this charset, then there should be no problems. But if you're dealing with characters which are not covered by this charset (e.g. chinese, hebrew, sanskrit, cyrillic, etc), then it will still fail. UTF-8 covers *any* character the mankind is aware of and thus better prepares your webapp for world domination.

Comment: Haha, world domination is every webapp eventual end-game. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you ... When i am using the **response.sendRedirect("/path/index.jsp?type=" + URLEncoder.encode(e.getType(), "UTF-8")**, My problem got fixed...

When we are using the response.sendRedirect(): We should encode the URL by the URLEncoder.encode() function then only.. it will be encoded correctly..

Thanks again...